# Equivelant of contains() selector in BeautifulSoup/Python

Tags: jquery, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

With jQuery selectors you can select a div that contains the innerText "John" with `$("div:contains('John')")`, so you could match the second `<div>` in:

```
<div>Bill</div>
<div>John</div>
<div>Joe</div>
```

How can I do this in Python's Beautiful Soup, or some other Python Module?

I just watched [a lecture on scraping form PyCon 2010](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2010-scrape-the-web-strategies-for-programming-websites-that-don-t-expected-it-3378693) where he mentions you can use CSS selectors in lxml.. Do I have to use that, or is there a way just with the Soup?

Background: Asking for the purpose of parsing a scraped web page.

Comment: Do you really want `contains`, or do you just need equality?

Comment: contains is nicer, but it seems like the answer provided thus far could be easily modified to accomodate that

Comment: If you're used to jquery selectors, you might be interested in the pyquery library: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more concise way using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method%3a%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20%2a%2akwargs%29):

```
>>> soup('div', text='John')
[u'John']
>>> import re
>>> soup('div', text=re.compile('Jo'))
[u'John', u'Joe']
```

`soup()` is equivalent to `soup.findAll()`. You could use string, regular expression, arbitrary function to select what you need.

stdlib's [`ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is enough in your case:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as etree

xml = """
    <div>Bill</div>
    <div>John</div>
    <div>Joe</div>
"""
root = etree.fromstring("<root>%s</root>" % xml)
for div in root.getiterator('div'):
    if "John" in div.text:
       print(etree.tostring(div))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("""
... <div>Bill</div>
... <div>John</div>
... <div>Joe</div>
... """)
# equality
>>> [tag for tag in soup.findAll('div') if tag.text == 'John']
[<div>John</div>]
# containment
>>> [tag for tag in soup.findAll('div') if 'John' in tag.text]
[<div>John</div>]
```

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful Soup now supports the `:contains` Selector!

To search for a `div` containing the text `John`, try:

```
html = """
<div>Bill</div>
<div>John</div>
<div>Joe</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

>>> print(soup.select_one("div:contains('John')"))
<div>John</div>
```

---

Note: To use a Selector use [`.select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)  instead of `.find()`, or `select()` instead of `find_all()`.

Comment: I think this was added in BeautifulSoup version  4.7.0

Comment: The pseudo class ':contains' is deprecated, ':-soup-contains' should be used moving forward